# Calculate stock position balance

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe that represents stock prices over time:

```
            close
date    
2000-01-01  146.1875
2001-01-01  128.8000
2002-01-01  115.5000
2003-01-01  91.0700
2004-01-01  111.2300
2005-01-01  120.3000
2006-01-01  126.7000
```

Assuming I purchase $1000 of stock at each row, I wish to add a column that tracks the balance over time. Here is where I am at so far:

```py
df['deposit'] = 1000
df['close_pct_change'] = df['close'].pct_change()
df['close_pct_change'].iloc[0] = 0
df['balance'] = df['deposit']
df['balance'] = df['deposit'] + (df['balance'].shift(-1, fill_value=0) + (df['balance'].shift(-1, fill_value=0) * df['close_pct_change']))
```

Here's the result:

```
            close   deposit close_pct_change    balance
date                
2000-01-01  146.1875    1000    0.000000    2000.000000
2001-01-01  128.8000    1000    -0.118940   1881.060282
2002-01-01  115.5000    1000    -0.103261   1896.739130
2003-01-01  91.0700     1000    -0.211515   1788.484848
2004-01-01  111.2300    1000    0.221368    2221.368178
2005-01-01  120.3000    1000    0.081543    2081.542749
2006-01-01  126.7000    1000    0.053200    2053.200333
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong. Please can someone advise how to add a column that shows the balance of the stock position if an additional $1000 is purchased at each row.

Comment: What do you mean by balance of the stock position? Is your balance column based on just your deposit or on already owned stock values? It might be helpful if you explain what you're trying to do mathematically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easiest to do this in three steps:

1) Make a `'new_shares'` column that is how many shares you can buy with your $1000:

```
# If you can buy partial shares:
df['new_shares'] = 1000 / df['close']
```

```
# If you can only buy whole shares:
df['new_shares'] = 1000 // df['close']
```

2) Make a `'total shares'` column that is a sum of all shares bought up to that point in time using [pandas.Series.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['total_shares'] = df['new_shares'].cumsum()
```

3) Make your `'balance'` column that is the share price times the amount of shares owned at that time:

```
df['balance'] = df['close'] * df['total_shares']
```

Full code example using whole shares approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    close = [146.1875, 128.8, 115.5, 91.07, 111.23, 120.3, 126.7]
    ),
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex([
        '2000-01-01', 
        '2001-01-01',
        '2002-01-01', 
        '2003-01-01',
        '2004-01-01', 
        '2005-01-01',
        '2006-01-01',
    ]).date,
)

df['new_shares'] = 1000 // df['close']
df['total_shares'] = df['new_shares'].cumsum()
df['balance'] = df['close'] * df['total_shares']
print(df)
```

[python tutor link to code example](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20close%20%3D%20%5B146.1875,%20128.8,%20115.5,%2091.07,%20111.23,%20120.3,%20126.7%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%29,%0A%20%20%20%20index%20%3D%20pd.DatetimeIndex%28%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2000-01-01',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2001-01-01',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2002-01-01',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2003-01-01',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2004-01-01',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2005-01-01',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2006-01-01',%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%29.date,%0A%29%0A%0Adf%5B'new_shares'%5D%20%3D%201000%20//%20df%5B'close'%5D%0Adf%5B'total_shares'%5D%20%3D%20df%5B'new_shares'%5D.cumsum%28%29%0Adf%5B'balance'%5D%20%3D%20df%5B'close'%5D%20*%20df%5B'total_shares'%5D%0Aprint%28df%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=15&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the `shift` won't give you the previous calculated balance as it is not iterative but static which means that `shift` will give you all `1000` and not calculated balance.

So, In order to do this, there is no vectorized way, without a loop as such because of the iterative nature of the problem,

Reset index to have a numeric index for easier iteration

```
>>> df = df.reset_index()
>>> df
         date     close  deposit  close_pct_change  balance
0  2000-01-01  146.1875     1000          0.000000     1000
1  2001-01-01  128.8000     1000         -0.118940     1000
2  2002-01-01  115.5000     1000         -0.103261     1000
3  2003-01-01   91.0700     1000         -0.211515     1000
4  2004-01-01  111.2300     1000          0.221368     1000
5  2005-01-01  120.3000     1000          0.081543     1000
6  2006-01-01  126.7000     1000          0.053200     1000
```

#### CODE

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'balance'] = (
        df.loc[i-1, 'balance'] + 
        df.loc[i, 'deposit'] +
        (
            df.loc[i-1, 'balance'] *
            df.loc[i, 'close_pct_change']
        )
    )
```

#### OUTPUT

```
>>> df
         date     close  deposit  close_pct_change      balance
0  2000-01-01  146.1875     1000          0.000000  1000.000000
1  2001-01-01  128.8000     1000         -0.118940  1881.060282
2  2002-01-01  115.5000     1000         -0.103261  2686.820362
3  2003-01-01   91.0700     1000         -0.211515  3118.517146
4  2004-01-01  111.2300     1000          0.221368  4808.857605
5  2005-01-01  120.3000     1000          0.081543  6200.985075
6  2006-01-01  126.7000     1000          0.053200  7530.879543
```

Comment: I think this answer misses a key assumption noted in the question. They are adding $1000 of stock to their position at every row (or year) so balance should be growing over time unless the stock price takes a major dive.